# Creating Production OAuth Client for a Desktop App with redirect URI

Tags: google-oauth

I'm in the process of verifying my application, but Google is requesting that I create a **PRODUCTION** OAuth client with One redirect URI and/or authrozied JavaScript origins URL.

I've poked around everywhere I can think of but I cannot find where I would:

1. Create a Production OAuth Client - When I create an OAuth Client for my Desktop App, there aren't any options besides Application name
2. Set a redirect URI and/or authorized JavaScript origins URL - This seems to be applicable to Web Applications, but not Desktop Apps.

I've gone back and forth with support, but I can't get a clear answer. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the exact same problem, would you please post your youtube verification video? I'm getting rejected because of the url at the end of the process is localhost!

Answer (score 2):

Production Oauth clients are clients that do not have localhost set in the redirect uri or the JavaScript origin. That's probably what they are detecting.

If you have any other clients in this project the first thing i would do is go and check that they don't have localhost set as their redirect Uris or JavaScript origins.

If all you have in this project is desktop applications then continue reading.

## OOB flow deprecation.

When creating a desktop app you can only change one thing that being the name

[image]
*(Note: This client was deleted after image taken you cant use it )*

In the background google has added a redirect uri of urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob and added it to the client.  This basically says to the system return the authorization token back to the same place it came from.

Back to your issue:

You are probably being hit by the new [Making Google OAuth interactions safer by using more secure OAuth flows](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html) changes.

These changes mainly effect desktop applications.   Ordinally the desktop client type used. The OAuth out-of-band (oob) flow.  This flow used a refresh token called.

> redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob or urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto or oob

The new changes removes that flow [dates-oob](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html#dates-oob) and its kicking in this week.

It sounds like by the error message you are getting that they are totally removing that type of client.  I was assured by Google that we would be given a grace period in which developers would have time to update their apps to use the new system.  I question wither or not this also counted for verification.

If this is the case then I have no solution but I can contact google for you to see if there is any issues with verification and desktop apps now.

Comment: If you can verify that you do not have any web apps that are effected by the first part of my answer.   I will send off an email to google to find out if there is any issue with verifying desktop applications due to this change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm new to Stackoverflow so my upvote didn't show, but know it was given! I only have one client for the project and it is a desktop app type (I deleted the other clients when trying to narrow down my issue, though those too were desktop OAuth clients).

Comment: I will email someone on the auth team see if we cant track down the issue.   I will let you know when i hear something.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help! Stackoverflow says I need 15 rep points to have my upvote show, but I'll lurk around and see if I can get those points up and get you that credit.

Comment: I have serval contact methods in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) but if you have twitter "[@LindaLawtonDK](https://twitter.com/LindaLawtonDK)" send me a private DM.   With your project Id my google contact will look into it.  Remember send it private do not post your project id here.

Comment: Finally got my application verified, the solution to my problem was to change the Application name. I was using 'YouTube Demo', and changing it to 'YouTube Production' as suggested helped get it across the finish line.

Comment: In my team we heavily rely on generating token.json using oob method that only need to do copy and pasting the code in the terminal, since our project mostly use desktop apps.

Hy @DaImTo could you elaborate how to enabling the oob flow via gcp console (or does this setting is there) rather than we using our localhost ip address

Comment: @cahyowhy you should be able to set the redirect uri to "http:/ /127.0.0.1".  The error response that comes back due to the fact that you don't have a localhost running  "h ttp://127.0.0.1/?code=COPY_THIS_CODE".  Let me know if it works with GCP I haven tried.