# Debug redirect_url in oauth2 flow

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We are using Go server side code to interact with Google Ads REST API.

Namely, we authenticate it with help of `"golang.org/x/oauth2"` and
`"golang.org/x/oauth2"`packages.

In May (and recently again) we've got a email from Google regarding deprecation
Out-of-band flow, essentially rewording of [this
one](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html).

But additionally to common information, Google email listed account, which we
are using to authenticate, as being used in OOB flow and going to be blocked.

We checked our sources and available sources of mentioned packages but was not
able to find redirect URIs which are said to be used for OOB flow as one of
those:

- redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
- urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto
- oob

We explicitly use `http://localhost` in our code and long-live refresh token
(which seems never expires).

We also tried to use `tcpdump` to monitor our API calls, but was not able to
learn much from it, because calls are made via https and, therefore, encrypted.

We considered to use man-in-the-middle kind of proxy like
https://www.charlesproxy.com/, but haven't tried it yet, because it become
non-free and because of complexity of setup.

We tried to log our requests to API endpoint with custom `RoundTripper`, but
have not spotted anything suspicious. It seems that we're using refresh token
only and exchange of `code` to `refresh token` just never happen in the code.
Because of this, we don't think that further logging or monitoring with
decrypting https packages may help (but we open to suggestions how to do it better).

Finally, we decided to create a new OAuth 2 Client in the Google console with
fresh set of client id, client secret and refresh token. We obtained a new
refresh token with [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l) and replaced
credentials in our configuration. But still, we are not sure that new account
will not be blocked by Google due OOB deprication, because seemingly it looks
the same as old one.

Questions:

- Why may Google mark our account as OOB?
- How can we ensure that newly created account will not be blocked?

Answer (score 1):

Same here.
I find out [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71348367), that says "Desktop" type of Credentials uses OOB by default. Probably you need to create new Credentials with type "Web"